# Entity Framework Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to make a really simple entity Framework Code First project, but can't manage to solve a "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." when I'm trying to retrieve data from my database.

I have a unique class :

```
public class TestStylo
{
    [Key]
    public int TestStyloID { get; set; }
    StyloType styloType { get; set; }
    public string name;

    public TestStylo(StyloType styloType, string name)
    {
        this.styloType = styloType;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public StyloType getTypeStylo{
        get { return styloType; }
    }


}
public enum StyloType
{
    pen,
    wood,
    gold
}
```

my Model is :

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
     public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public  DbSet<TestStylo> MyStylos { get; set; }
}
```

And my App.Config is :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TestCodeFirst.Model1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My connectionString is working, I can manually open and see my database and it's content.
When I try to add content to my database I use :

```
using (Model1 db = new Model1())
            {
                TestStylo stylo = new TestStylo(StyloType.pen,"numberOne");
                db.MyStylos.Add(stylo);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

and it works for the most part (it only insert the ID .. but I'll see that later)

But when I try to retrieve with :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Model1 db = new Model1())
            {
                var stylos = from order in db.MyStylos
                              select order;

                ...
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an `"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."` with an Inner-Exception `{"The class 'TestCodeFirst.TestStylo' has no parameterless constructor."}`.

Why am I getting such an error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual error is presented in the inner exception:

> The class 'TestCodeFirst.TestStylo' has no parameterless constructor.

All entities should have a parameterless constructor in order to be used by Entity Framework.

You can simply add this constructor to your entity:

```
public class TestStylo
{
    [Key]
    public int TestStyloID { get; set; }
    StyloType styloType { get; set; }
    public string name;

    public TestStylo(StyloType styloType, string name)
    {
        this.styloType = styloType;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public StyloType getTypeStylo{
        get { return styloType; }
    }

    // Add this:
    public TestStylo()
    {

    }
}
```

This constructor can actually be `internal` or `private` if you do not want to expose the public constructor.

Comment: It fixes my error indeed.
But it seems that it's inserting in the database without any parameter but the TestStyloID, how can I make sure I save the StyloType and name in the database too ?

Comment: @Belte You can keep using `TestStylo(StyloType styloType, string name)` constructor when you want to create an entity to be inserted. Parameterless constructor will be used by Entity Framework, f.i. when reading from database.

Comment: I am, I only added the empty constructor as you told me, and tried adding a getting and setter for my name field.
When debugging I can see that I'm inserting a `TestStylo` with a name and a type, but when retrieving my data I strangely only have an ID, a type, but null as name.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to remove EntityFramework  and EntityFramework.SqlServer folders from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL